# Dynamically loading SQL tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to dynamically access some SQL tables hopefully using the Entity Framework. Here's some pseudo code:

`var Account = DB.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 12345);`

which will return me an Account object and this contains some fields called "PREFIX", "CAMPAIGN ID" and further information about the accounts are stored in separate SQL tables with the naming convention of PREFIX_CAMPAIGNID_MAIN.

The tables all have the same fields so I was thinking of creating a new Entity that isn't mapped anywhere and then dynamically loading it, like so:

`var STA01_MAIN = new MyAccount(); // my "un-mapped" entity`

`DB.LoadTable('STA01_MAIN').LoadInto(STA01_MAIN);`

I can now get anything about the STA01_MAIN account: `STA01_MAIN.AccountId`.

So my question is: how do I access these tables using the Entity Framework?

Comment: You will map them, you will query them directly with SQL or you will not access them. Adam's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think EF has a LoadTable and LoadInto method, but `ObjectOntext.ExecuteStoreQuery` might be what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx

This should let you execute an arbitrary query against your database, and then map the results to an arbitrary type that you specify (even if it's not otherwise mapped in EF).

It goes without saying that you would be responsible for putting together a query that supplied the necessary columns for mapping into the destination type, and also adjusting said query when this type changes.

Here's some further discussion concerning its usage

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/44cf5582-63f8-4f81-8029-7b43469c028d/

Have you considered mapping all of these tables (with the identical columns) into an inheritance relationship in EF, and then querying them as

`db.BaseTypes.OfType<SpecificType>().Where(/*.....*/);`

Comment: +1 Correct answer. This inheritance model is called Table per Class (TPC).

Comment: That seems what I was looking for, thanks Adam! I would of mapped all of the tables but they are literally thousands of them (it's fun waiting for VS to load them all).